# How To Avoiding Recursive Trigger In Salesforce

Tags: trigger

How Recursive Trigger Is  Working In Salesforce I  have Lot Of Confusion In Recursive trigger. Can u give me  Explain With Example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many developers face this issue because of a recursive trigger. For example, in an 'after update' trigger, a developer could be performing an update operation and this would lead to recursive call, and the error:

> "maximum trigger depth exceeded"

Resolution  In order to avoid the situation of recursive call, make sure your trigger is getting executed only one time. To do so, you can create a class with a static Boolean variable with default value true.

In the trigger, before executing your code keep a check that the variable is true or not.Once you check, make the variable false.

**Class:-**
*==========*

```
public Class checkRecursive{
    private static boolean run = true;
    public static boolean runOnce(){
    if(run){
     run=false;
     return true;
    }else{
        return run;
    }
    }
}
```

**Recursive Trigger:-**
*=====================*